# Grails database migration plugin - Java heap space

Tags: database, grails, heap-memory

I am running grails 1.3.7 and using the grails database migration plugin version database-migration-1.0

The problem I have is I have a migration change set.  That is pulling blobs out of a table and writing them to disk.  When running through this migration though I am running out of heap space.  I was thinking I would need to flush and clear the session to free up some space however I am having difficulty getting access to the session from within the migration. BTW The reason it's in a migration is we are moving away from storing files in oracle and putting them on disk

I have tried

```
SessionFactoryUtils.getSession(sessionFactory, true)
```

I have also tried

```
SecurityRequestHolder.request.getSession(false)   //request in null -> not surprising
```

---

```
changeSet(author: "userone", id: "saveFilesToDisk-1") {
    grailsChange{
        change{
            def fileIds = sql.rows("""SELECT id FROM erp_file""")
            for (row in fileIds) {
                def erpFile = ErpFile.get(row.id)
                erpFile.writeToDisk()
                session.flush()
                session.clear()
                propertyInstanceMap.get().clear()
            }
            ConfigurationHolder.config.erp.ErpFile.persistenceMode = previousMode
        }
    }
}
```

**Any help would be greatly appreciated.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application context will be automatically available in your migration as `ctx`.  You can get the session like this:

```
def session = ctx.sessionFactory.currentSession
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  I went back and read the migration plugin documentation a bit closer.  <kicking>myself</kicking>

Answer (score 0):

To access session, you can use withSession closure like this:

```
Book.withSession { session ->
    session.clear()
}
```

But, this may not be the reason why your app run out of heap space. If the data volume is large, then

```
 def fileIds = sql.rows("""SELECT id FROM erp_file""")
    for (row in fileIds) {
        ..........
    }
```

will consume up your space. Try to process the data with pagination. Don't load all the data at once.